# Performing repeated additions on float or double values produces unexpected results

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I found a but in my code and after some searching I realized that some floating operations that I was performing produced the wrong results. So I typed the following loop:

```
 float f = 0f;
     for(int i =0; i<15; i++){
        f+= 10.1f;
        System.out.println(f);
}
```

But in the results I get unexpected additional decimal values:

```
10.1
20.2
30.300001
40.4
50.5
60.6
70.7
80.799995
90.899994
100.99999
111.09999
121.19999
131.29999
141.4
151.5
```

What is going on here and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't "prevent" it. What you need to do instead is expect it and compensate.

See: What [Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: There are ways to perform the desired calculations without errors, so it is incorrect to state that you cannot prevent it. It is possible to perform the arithmetic with Java floating-point in such a way that the exact results can be recovered after the rounding errors of computation, and it is also possible to perform the arithmetic in other ways, without using Java floating-point. Furthermore, this answer does not explain what errors occurred in the code in the question.

Comment: The point is to understand that computational floating-point arithmetic has its inherent problems and that programmers should understand it and compensate.

Answer (score 3):

The numbers are stored as binary, and at a certain precision the representation between binary and decimal is not perfect, essentially leading to 'rounding errors'. If precision is of importance in this scenario, try using BigDecimal instead

Comment: In Java, floating-point numbers are stored with a binary base, not “in binary”.

Comment: BigDecimal is prone to errors, just as binary-based floating-point is, so it is not a panacea for floating-point arithmetic. People should not be advised to switch to BigDecimal without being advised of its shortcomings as well.

Answer (score 1):

Two operations in your code cause errors:

- The conversion of the source text `10.1f` to `float`. This conversion is inexact because 10.1 cannot be exactly represented in the floating-point format Java uses.
- The additions of `10.1f` to previous values of `f`. In many of these additions, the exact sum will not fit completely in the floating-point format, so the result must be rounded.

You can modify the loop to avoid accumulating errors:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    f = (i+1) * 101 / 10.f;
    System.out.println(f);
}
```

When you write the code in this way, `f` will still not be exactly 10.1•(*i*+1) in every iteration, but it will be the closest representable value. In this new version, `(i+1) * 101` is calculated exactly, and `10.f` is exactly 10 because 10 is representable in the floating-point format. This means that the only error is in the division operation. That operation will return the representable value closest to the exact result.

Java uses IEEE-754 binary floating-point, 32 bits for `float` and 64 bits for `double`. In those formats, a number is represented, basically, as an integer times a power of 2. In the 32-bit format, the integer must have magnitude less than 2<sup>24</sup>. The closest you can get to 10.1 in the 32-bit format is 5295309•2<sup>-19</sup>, which is 10.1000003814697265625.